# amsthm and citations using natbib

Tags: bibtex, natbib, amsthm

The standard way of combining a citation with the amsthm package is to use :

```
\begin{thm}[\citep{...}].
```

However, suppose I want to name a particular theorem I am referencing. If we were outside the amsthm environment, we could just use `\citep[Theorem blah]{...}`, but attempting to do this in amsthm creates errors, i.e. :

```
\begin{thm}[\citep[Theorem blah]{...}]
```

does not work.  Are there any ways to get around this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This has already been asked: you have to brace `\citep`: `\begin{thm}[{\citep[Theorem blah]{key}}]`; the linked question has `\cite`, but it's the same problem.

Comment: Apologies for the double post (I did try to look beforehand), and thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem: searching on the site is not always easy if you don't know the right keys: I looked for "theorem cite" and was lucky. Welcome again!